# How to check code for XAML files in Visual Studio upon building

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, build, code-analysis

I want to check XAML files in a Visual Studio project whenever I build projects.

In my specific case I want to ensure that whenever a control of a certain type is used in XAML a certain property of that control is set, but I'm looking for a general solution to perform code analysis for XAML.

In the past I used StyleCop to check styling rules for CS files, but it seems it is not possible to create a custom rule for XAML files - correct me if I'm wrong.

It is important that rules can be included in the solution and added to version control, so that all team members use the same rules.
And it would be nice to throw build errors if rules fail - just as it is possible with StyleCop.

Comment: I need to do the same exact thing. Did you achieve it?

Comment: We ended up building our own tool. We included a console program in our solution and ran the generated executable as post-build event for the projects we needed. If you Console.WriteLine the error in a certain format, VS build will recognize it correctly and show it in the error list: FilePath[(LineNumber[,ColumnNumber])]: MessageType[ MessageCode]: Description

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Will think about it.